# Certificate mis-match issue installing Android Test App on AVD using Jenkins

Tags: android, ant, certificate, automated-tests, jenkins

I am having an issue using Jenkins to build and install my Android test project (page down for the actual error).

I have created a simple Android project and corresponding test project, in Eclipse.  I have executed the following:

```
android update project -p App1
android update test-project -m ../App1 -p App1Test
```

I can run the test project in Eclipse, the projects build, install on the AVD (already running) and execute correctly.

Also, I can execute the following successfully from the command line:

```
D:\> adb uninstall com.ss
```

(remove App1 from AVD if it is already installed)

```
D:\workspace\App1> ant clean debug
```

then

```
D:\workspace\App1Test> ant all clean debug install test
```

Again, App1-test-debug.apk and App1-debug.apk are built and installed on the AVD, tests are executed.

The problem is when I am trying to do this using Jenkins.

I create 2 Jobs:

- App1 - ant targets: `clean debug`
- App1Test - ant targets: `all clean debug install test`

App1Test is configured to run after App1 is built successfully.

App1 job runs correctly, creating App1-debug.apk.

App1Test *appears* to run correctly up to the install task.
App1-debug.apk and App1Test-debug.apk are created, but there is an error in the `INSTALL` task:

> install:
>        [echo] Installing D:\Jenkins\workspace\App1Test\bin\App1Test-debug.apk onto default
>   emulator or device...
>        [exec]   pkg: /data/local/tmp/App1Test-debug.apk
>        [exec] Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES]
>        [exec] 40 KB/s (14127 bytes in 0.343s)
>
> -set-mode-check:
>
> -set-debug-files:
>
> install:
>        [echo] Installing D:\Jenkins\workspace\App1\bin\App1-debug.apk onto default emulator or device...
>        [exec]   pkg: /data/local/tmp/App1-debug.apk
>        [exec] Success
>        [exec] 433 KB/s (13883 bytes in 0.031s)
>
> installd:
>
> -test-project-check:
>
> test:
>        [echo] Running tests ...
>        [exec] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=ActivityManagerService
>        [exec] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: Error=Permission Denial: starting instrumentation
>   ComponentInfo{com.ss.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner} from
>   pid=2520, uid=2520 not allowed because package com.ss.test does not
>   have a signature matching the target com.ss
>        [exec] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
>        [exec] java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting instrumentation
>   ComponentInfo{com.ss.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner} from
>   pid=2520, uid=2520 not allowed because package com.ss.test does not
>   have a signature matching the target com.ss

I understand that both App1 and App1Test need to be signed with the same certificate, which in this case should be the same debug cert.  Why would a different certificate be used for each project?

The full log shows that both apks are signed with the debug cert:

```
-package:
[apkbuilder] Current build type is different than previous build: forced apkbuilder run.
[apkbuilder] Creating App1-debug-unaligned.apk and signing it with a debug key...
```

and:

```
-package:
[apkbuilder] Current build type is different than previous build: forced apkbuilder run.
[apkbuilder] Creating App1Test-debug-unaligned.apk and signing it with a debug key...
```

I followed [Jenkins:Building and testing an Android app](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+an+Android+app+and+test+project), with one exception.  I could not get the test project to build if I used the

```
tested.project.dir=
```

property in the Advanced Ant section.  I simply set the correct value in the projects `ant.properties` file, and committed to SVN:

```
tested.project.dir=../App1
```

(sure this is not causing the issue, but though best to document it).

I am really tearing my hair out over this one, if some one can help me regain my sanity, there will be **BIG LOVE** coming your way.

Using:
android-sdk-16

SVN

ant 1.8

Eclipse Indigo

Answer (score 1):

Solved....

A test apk must have been installed on the device using a different keystore (not sure how).

So by executing:

```
adb uninstall com.ss.test
```

The 'new' test apk installs fine.